# selecting last element with sql select last and turing it into php variable

Tags: php, sql, variables, select

```
$sql="SELECT LAST(product_id) FROM producten";
$sql_result = $dbh -> query ($sql);
```

I want to select the last element from the column and turn in into a php variable called $product_id.
But I dont know how. Can anyone please tell me??

Comment: MySQL? SQL Server? DB2? What're we talking about here?

Comment: You probably want:  `select max(product_id) from production`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reverse order and take the first one

```
SELECT * FROM producten ORDER BY product_id DESC LIMIT 0,1
```